# iOS change height for orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen, orientation, c-preprocessor

I've got this conditional float in my loadView method, which works fine for the two devices. However, I've had the worst time trying to find a way to make these change for orientation.

I have this in my Prefix.pch:

```
#define dDeviceOrientation [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
#define isPortrait  UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(dDeviceOrientation)
#define isLandscape UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(dDeviceOrientation)
#define isFaceUp    dDeviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp   ? YES : NO
#define isFaceDown  dDeviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown ? YES : NO
```

I have this in my loadView method (portrait because I want to know that works first...:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenHeight = CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds);     
     float Y;
if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)){        
    NSLog(@"%f", screenHeight);
    if (isPortrait){
 Y = (screenHeight-(0.14*screenHeight));
    }else{ 
    }
} else {
    if (isPortrait){
        Y = (screenHeight-(0.25*screenHeight));
    }else{            
    }
}
settingsButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, Y, 40, 40.0);
aboutButton.frame = CGRectMake(75, Y, 40, 40.0);
```

There are many solutions out there, but I am not so sharp.

=====

Matt Neuburg guided me to consider NSLayoutConstraint... This is what I mustered:

```
[self.view addSubview:ab];
[self.view addSubview:sb];
//constraints
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:ab
                                //ab's relation to the left edge
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading                                      
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading                                      
                                  multiplier:1.0f
                                  constant:7.f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
              constraintWithItem:ab
              //ab's relation to the bottom edge
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:self.view
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
              multiplier:1.0f
              constant:-10.f];

[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:sb
            //sb's identical relation to the bottom edge ( violation of DRY but I'm in a hurry :'( //
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
              multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
              //SB's relation to the leading edge
              constraintWithItem:sb
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:self.view
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
              multiplier:1.0f
              constant:75.0f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

And this is the result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have implied, the problem is that `viewDidLoad` is way too soon. I give a bunch of solutions in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#SECrotationevents

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is an excellent place. Best of all in iOS 6 is just give everything good constraints and then you don't need any code on rotation at all.

Comment: Thank you Matt! Constraints were the key.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I dont really know what your goal is, but I'm quite sure that if you move this code to the

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

method, your problem will be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this method?

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // Your code here
}
```